# Drag and Drop on UI

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to create a simple drag and drop game using Unity UI objects.

My objects right now are images with scripts attached to them. My script is using `OnBeginDrag`, `OnDrag` and `OnEndDrag` events which works fine when I want to move image objects.

However image objects are always square and I want to detect drag only when mouse is on specifid area. So I created a Polygon Collider 2D on my image and adjusted it to shape I wanted. Unfortunetly I can't make it work at all.

```
public void OnBeginDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    var canvas = FindInParents<Canvas>(gameObject);

    itemBeingDragged = gameObject;
    m_DraggingPlane = canvas.transform as RectTransform;
}

public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    SetDraggedPosition(eventData);
}

public void OnEndDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    itemBeingDragged = null;
    int i = 0;
    foreach (Vector3 hex in otherHexes)
    {
        Vector3 rayBeginning = hex + transform.position;
        rays = Physics2D.RaycastAll(rayBeginning, Vector2.zero);


        if (rays.Length > 1)                                                                                //if there are other elements in RayCast
        {
            foreach (RaycastHit2D ray in rays)
            {
                if (ray.transform.gameObject != gameObject && ray.transform.tag == "Hex")                    //if element is not self and is a HexGrid
                {
                    SuccessfulDrag(ray, i);
                }
                else if (ray.transform.gameObject != gameObject && ray.transform.tag == "GetOut")            //if element is not self and is another puzzle
                {
                    FailedDrag();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        else if (rays.Length == 1 && rays[0].transform.gameObject == gameObject)                             //if there is only one element and it's self
        {
            FailedDrag();
            break;
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/423378/how-do-you-create-complex-collision-geometry-to-ma.html - this may help

Comment: @Clint Thanks for answer, but it's not quite what I need. I know how to create complex colliders as I used Polygon Collider 2D to create the shape I wanted. What I don't know tho is how to apply my drag and drop script so it uses those colliders instead of sprite. When I try to apply my script to an object without image it simply doesn't work. It doesn't detect any drag-events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I googled a bit more and I found a solution. Just create a class with this code inside and put it on the object that you want to drag by it's collider.

using UnityEngine;

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(RectTransform), typeof(Collider2D))]
public class Collider2DRaycastFilter : MonoBehaviour, ICanvasRaycastFilter
{
Collider2D myCollider;
RectTransform rectTransform;

void Awake()
{
    myCollider = GetComponent<Collider2D>();
    rectTransform = GetComponent<RectTransform>();
}

public bool IsRaycastLocationValid(Vector2 screenPos, Camera eventCamera)
{
    var worldPoint = Vector3.zero;
    var isInside = RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToWorldPointInRectangle(
        rectTransform,
        screenPos,
        eventCamera,
        out worldPoint
    );
    if (isInside)
        isInside = myCollider.OverlapPoint(worldPoint);
    return isInside;
}
}
```